# Bootstrap Typeahead Async - multiple values

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

Im trying to implement Bootstrap Typeahead in my AngularJS project and I came across an issue with values.
Im loading the content via $http from my Django API server. For now, I can lookup for any item I want and display it's name, but what I need is to display "title" but return "id" via ng-model back to the controller.
Do you have any working example of doing this?

http://pastebin.com/xtype9J4

Comment: Could you please show what you have so far?

Comment: I've add pastebin into the post

Comment: How about having an array of company objects, with each object having a title and an id?

Comment: Ive been thinking about this but how can i display A and return via ng-model B? I mean if you could give me an example...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead, so I'd suggest having a look at the last example.
Looking at the DOM, your code could look something like this:

`uib-typeahead="company as company.name for company in getCompanies($viewValue)"`

This pretty much contains exactly what you need. Additionally, take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select and https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions for further examples, as AngularUI has a similar (if not identical) approach.

Comment: thanks, but this approach gives me company.name and also company.name is returned back to the controller but I need to return back company.id instead. company.name only is working fine but does not do what I need :/

Comment: Tried `uib-typeahead="company.name for company in getCompanies($viewValue)"` ?